# Remove the last page of pagination

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to hide / remove the last page of the pagination. 132 in my case.

!image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J7j2.png

I read the documention but none of arguments can hide the last page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Do you have an idea how can I made this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could just make some CSS rule that would hide the last page for you. For example, using `last-of-type` on the class similar to this:

```css
button.page:last-of-type {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="page">1</span>
<button class="page">2</span>
<button class="page">3</span>
<button class="page">4</span>
```